# Keeping XSLT Code DRY with 'if' Tests and 'value-of' Selects

Tags: xslt, dry

In XSLT, what is the preferred way to keep code DRY when it comes to 'if's?

At the moment I am doing this:

```
<xsl:if test="select/some/long/path">
    <element>
        <xsl:value-of select="select/some/long/path" />
    </element>
</xsl:if>
```

I would prefer to only write "select/some/long/path" once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see your point. When the path is 200 chars long the code can get messy.

You could just add it to a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="path" select="select/some/long/path"/>

<xsl:if test="$path">    
   <xsl:value-of select="$path" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: In this case the variable is a node so you can for example go:

    <xsl:variable name="path" select="select/some/long"/> <xsl:value-of select="$path/path" />

Answer (score 0):

Where is the difference between:

```
<xsl:if test="select/some/long/path">
  <xsl:value-of select="select/some/long/path" />
</xsl:if>
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="select/some/long/path" />
```

? If it does not exist, value-of will output an empty string (i.e.: nothing). So why the test?

Comment: I was just keeping the example simple. I am actually using it like the following:

  <xsl:if test="select/some/long/path">
    <element>
      <xsl:value-of select="select/some/long/path" />
    </element>
  </xsl:if>